# How to stretch textFields at JasperReports 3.5.2?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JaspeReports 3.5.2.

I want to stretch my fields vertically, basically If some text is too long I want wrap it, and then all the fields below I want to move down.

As is:
[image]

To be:
[image]

Is it possible? If Jasper in version 3.5.2 support things like this?

I read about this issue, and many people said that:

1. every filed have to use `isStretchWithOverflow="true"`
2. every reportElement have to use `positionType="Float"` and 
   `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"`
3. And the last one: I have to group my elements by row

Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="552" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="30">
      <style name="normal" isDefault="true" fontName="Lucida Sans Typewriter" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
       <pageHeader>
             <band height="300" splitType="Stretch">
                    <elementGroup>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="189" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="131" y="189" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="300" y="189" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="430" y="189" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </elementGroup>
                    <elementGroup>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="199" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="131" y="199" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="300" y="199" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="430" y="199" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </elementGroup>
                    <elementGroup>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="209" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="131" y="209" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="300" y="209" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="430" y="209" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </elementGroup>

                    <elementGroup>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="219" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="131" y="219" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="300" y="219" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="430" y="219" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </elementGroup>

                    <elementGroup>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="229" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="131" y="229" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="300" y="229" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="430" y="229" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </elementGroup>
                    <elementGroup>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="239" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="131" y="239" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="300" y="239" width="130" height="18" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font isBold="true" size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                           <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" mode="Transparent" x="430" y="239" width="173" height="16" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"/>
                           <textElement>
                                  <font size="7"/>
                           </textElement>
                           <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["aaa"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField> 
                    </elementGroup>
             </band>       
       </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I know that stretching and wrapping are two different things. I thought that I need both of them, because if I use only isStretchWithOverflow="true" the field will fill with the text to the end of textfield and then will wrap to the next line(line below) and will cover text below, am I right?

Comment: @przemoinho Yes, it is possible. Your template need to be modified a little: `<elementGroup>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement key="textField" style="normal" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="209" width="130" height="10"/>
     <textElement>
      <font size="7" isBold="true"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Value"]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>` You should set the same *height* for all textFields at elementGroup

Comment: setting the same height for all textFields fixed my problem